# Reusing the "Add New Contact" screen

Tags: swift, addressbookui

I'm developing a user details management app...and am keen to reuse the existing user interface that comes along with the standard iOS Address Book functionality for adding a new user...I would, however, need to customise the properties to suit the needs of my application.
I'd appreciate any tips on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance,
Regds,
Gaurav

Comment: Just do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Hey Matt...Your book "Programming iOS 8", has probably given me the pointers I was looking for...Am going to try inheriting from the ABNewPersonViewController and let you know how I fare...Thanks

Comment: Hey Matt...It appears the New Contact screen cannot be modified..." The interface allows the user to fill in all properties of a new contact. You cannot limit the properties displayed."...I am interested in customising the set of fields that appear...Is there a way around or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Good question! I think the tree to bark up, if limiting the properties displayed is really important to you, is to pick a controller that _does_ let you limit the properties displayed, like an editable ABPersonViewController. I'm not saying that the limitations on ABNewPersonViewController aren't annoying - frankly, this whole part of the interface is desperately crufty in my opinion. But the alternative is to write your own interface from scratch (might not be easy, depending on your goals), or else just to abandon your desire to limit the displayed properties.